# How do I find the largest sequence in a string that is repeated at least once?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

Trying to solve the following problem:

> Given a string of arbitrary length, find the longest substring that occurs more than one time within the string, with no overlaps.

For example, if the input string was `ABCABCAB`, the correct output would be `ABC`.  You couldn't say `ABCAB`, because that only occurs twice where the two substrings overlap, which is not allowed.

Is there any way to solve this reasonably quickly for strings containing a few thousand characters?

(And before anyone asks, this is not homework.  I'm looking at ways to optimize the rendering of Lindenmayer fractals, because they tend to take excessive amounts of time to draw at high iteration levels with a naive turtle graphics system.)

Comment: would `ABC` be somehow rated higher (lexicographical ordering?) above `BCA` or `CAB` which also have the same length?

Comment: what is the answer for string `AAA`? `A` or `AA`?

Comment: @Piotrek: 'A', because there is no set of more than one `AA` that do not overlap.

Comment: @RobotWoods: Not lexicographical ordering; I was mostly just using that as an example.  Any substrings of equal length should be equally valid. If you need a tiebreaker, the winner is the one that occurs the most times. If you still need a tiebreaker, then (and this is completely arbitrary) the winner is the one whose first iteration occurs earliest in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example for a string of length 11, which you can generalize

- Set chunk length to floor(11/2) = 5
- Scan the string in chunks of 5 characters left to looking for repeats.  There will be 3 comparisons

```
    Left      Right
    Offset    Offset
     0         5
     0         6
     1         5
```

- If you found a duplicate you're done. Otherwise reduce the chunk length to 4 and repeat until chunk length goes to zero.

Here's some (obviously untested) pseudocode:

```
String s
int len = floor(s.length/2)
for int i=len; i>0; i--
    for j=0; j<=len-(2*i); j++
        for k=j+i; k<=len-i; k++
            if s.substr(j,j+i) == s.substr(k,k+i)
                return s.substr(j,j+i)
return null
```

There may be an off-by-one error in there, but the approach should be sound (and minimal).

Comment: I think this is the obvious answer.

Comment: What if you had `ABCXABC`? Doesn't your solution assume the second occurrence is right after the first? Either way, your solution is (at least) `O(length^2)`, which I'm pretty sure is not optimal.

Comment: No, it doesn't assume that; it anchors the first substring, and then starts searching at the first character after the first substring, comparing chunks of the same size.  I don't think a solution can be better than O(n^2)... but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like a suffix tree problem. Create the suffix tree, then find the biggest compressed branch with more than one child (occurs more than once in the original string). The number of letters in that compressed branch should be the size of the biggest subsequence.

i found something similar here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/370396/java/java/Algorithm-wanted-longest-repeating-substring

Looks like it can be done in O(n).

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea. You better explain why for those who won't understand. +1

Comment: I clicked through the linked post to the descriptive article on there, and found the following example for "longest repeating substring": " `issi' in the case of `mississippi'".  This unfortunately violates the no-overlap rule.

Comment: yes, they don't have the constraint to avoid overlapping. that's why they take the whole path from the root to the leaf. if you don't want overlapping you should take only **one** compressed **branch**, which is `ssi`

Answer (score 0):

First we need to define the start symbol of our substring and define the length. Iterate all possible start positions then figure out the length doing binary search for the length (if you can find substr with lenght a, you may find with the longer length, function looks monotonous so bin search should be fine). Then find equal substring is N, using KMP or Rabin-Karp any linear algo is fine. Total N*N*log(N). Is that too much complexity?
The code is something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length();++i)
    {
        int l = i;
        int r = input.length();
        while(l <= r)
        {
            int middle = l + ((r - l) >> 1);
            Check if string [i;middle] can be found in initial string. Should be done in O(n); You need to check parts of initial string [0,i-1], [middle+1;length()-1];
            if (found)
                l = middle + 1;
            else
                r = middle - 1;
        }
    }
```

Make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Added to answer some more comments

Answer (score 0):

This type of analysis is often done in genome sequences. have a look at this paper. it has an efficient implemention (c++) for solving repeats: http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/17-4-4.pdf
might be what you are looking for